# Using on/off event bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to unbind an event.

My event is:

```
 $(window).on('drop', this.onFileSelect.bind(this));
```

Later I:

```
$(window).off('drop', this.onFileSelect.bind(this));
```

But I can still drop.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Without more context, difficult to say. Are you sure `this` is what you think it is in *both* cases? Can you produce a small example snippet to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Well, you could simply do `$(window).off('drop')` even though that's not your problem here.

Comment: $(window).off('drop') would be enough

Comment: That might be the problem actually - if .bind returns a function, which I assume it does, calling off with it would try to turn off the click handler for that instance of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to identify event listeners in jQuery (typically for later removal) is to use [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/), and in your case:

```
$(window).on('drop.onfileselect', this.onFileSelect.bind(this));
```

Then:

```
$(window).off('drop.onfileselect');
```

Note that `onfileselect` is an arbitrary identifier I chose, you can provide your own (plugin) name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer works great! Quick questions, in general why is it good for one to use event namespacing?

Comment: Assume you've registered a `click` event handler and you're also using another plugin that registers its own `click` handler (say Bootstrap dialog / modal for example). Now you want to unbind your handler, simply calling `off('click')` would disable all `click` handlers (including the plugin handler), using a namespace lets you identify the handler specifically, not just simply *the click* handler but *my named click* handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that `bind()` return a new function. So the function you're trying to unbind is not the same of the function you are binding. jQuery then fail to properly unbind the event.

Save the reference of your function and use that reference:

```
var myFn = this.onFileSelect.bind(this);
$(window).on('drop', myFn);
$(window).off('drop', myFn);
```

Be sure that the variable is accessible by both scope.

---

That solution explain the problem. To solve your issue, you could A) do what I said in comment : `$(window).off('drop')`. B) Use namespace like [haim770's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413010/2324107). C) Use this answer (which is the worst solution IMO).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very good but like you say haim770 has it.

Comment: @panthro Yes I know, I just think it is important to know what `bind` really does. And also what the problem is ;)